# How to store my sms in sqlite database via onReceive method

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in which am not able to store my sms into sqlite database 
using onReceive method so please help me out with code snippet

public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) 
    {
        // Get SMS map from Intent
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

```
    String messages = "";

    if ( extras != null )
    {
        // Get received SMS array
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( SMS_EXTRA_NAME );

        // Get ContentResolver object for pushing encrypted SMS to incoming folder
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i )
        {
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

            String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
            String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

            messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";                    
            messages += body + "\n";

            // Here you can add any your code to work with incoming SMS
            // I added encrypting of all received SMS 

            putSmsToDatabase( contentResolver, sms );
        }

        // Display SMS message
        Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    // WARNING!!! 
    // If you uncomment next line then received SMS will not be put to incoming.
    // Be careful!
    this.abortBroadcast(); 
}

private void putSmsToDatabase( ContentResolver contentResolver, SmsMessage sms )
{
    // Create SMS row
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put( ADDRESS, sms.getOriginatingAddress() );
    values.put( DATE, sms.getTimestampMillis() );
    values.put( READ, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ );
    values.put( STATUS, sms.getStatus() );
    values.put( TYPE, MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX );
    values.put( SEEN, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN );
    try
    {
        String encryptedPassword= sms.getMessageBody().toString();
        //String encryptedPassword = StringCryptor.encrypt( new String(PASSWORD), sms.getMessageBody().toString() ); 
        values.put( BODY, encryptedPassword );
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) 
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    // Push row into the SMS table
    contentResolver.insert( Uri.parse( SMS_URI ), values );
}
```

Comment: show some code ,where you are struck.

Comment: This my code please help me out

Comment: Please  me out along with code snippet